# ASP.net JavaScript Event

Tags: javascript, asp.net, grid

i have a problem in my asp.net program. I have a function onDBLClick which is in JavaScript. The Grid from this function is in ModalPopupExtender. But the function dosn't work.

How i create the Grid:

```
 <asp:Panel ID="PanelSearchColor" runat="server" Width="750" Height ="" Style="border: solid; border-width: 4px; border-color: black; background-color: #FFFFFF;"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRecordHover="True"">

        <cc2:Grid ID="gridFoundColors" runat="server" AllowAddingRecords="False" AllowMultiRecordSelection="False" AllowColumnReordering="True" AllowColumnResizing="True"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRecordHover="True" FolderStyle="App_Themes/GRID/black_glass" PageSize="26"
                    ShowGroupsInfo="True" ShowTotalNumberOfPages="True"  AllowMultiRecordEditing="False">
                    <LocalizationSettings 
                        Grouping_GroupingAreaText="<%$Resources:Grid, gridGroupingAreaText %>"
                        LoadingText="<%$Resources:Grid, gridLoadingText %>" 
                        NoRecordsText="<%$Resources:Grid, gridNoRecordsText %>" 
                        Paging_PageSizeText="<%$Resources:Grid, gridPageSizeText %>"
                        Paging_PagesText="<%$Resources:Grid, gridPagesText %>" 
                        Paging_RecordsText="<%$Resources:Grid, gridRecordsText %> " 
                        Paging_TotalNumberOfPages="<%$Resources:Grid, gridTotalNumberOfPages %>"
                        Paging_OfText="<%$Resources:Grid, gridOfText %>" 
                        Paging_ToText="<%$Resources:Grid, gridToText %>" />
                    <ClientSideEvents OnClientDblClick="onDBLClick" />
                    <Columns>
                        <cc2:Column DataField="PE_NR" HeaderText="PE NR" Index="0" Visible="False">
                        </cc2:Column>
                        <cc2:Column DataField="KATALOG_NR" HeaderText="KATALOG_NR" Index="1" Width="375">
                        </cc2:Column>
                        <cc2:Column DataField="VERTRETER_NR" HeaderText="VERTRETER_NR" Index="2" Width="375">
                        </cc2:Column>
                    </Columns>                                
        </cc2:Grid>

         <script type="text/javascript">        
             function onDBLClick(iRecordIndex)
             {
                 var AuftragsID = gridFoundColors.Rows[iRecordIndex].Cells[0].Value;
                 var urlString = "Auftragserfassung.aspx?OpenID=";
                 var target = urlString.concat(AuftragsID);
                 window.alert(target);
                 window.location(target);
                 window.open(target);
            }
        </script>

         <asp:Button ID="DummyBTN23" runat="server"
                        Height="" meta:resourcekey="DummyBTN23" Text="<%$Resources:MusterglasFarbe, DummyBTN23 %>" Width="" />
    </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Instead of saying "doesn't work" you need to describe the behavior you're seeing, and what you expect to see.

Comment: It dosnt work. The program have to Open a new Tab with the URLString. But the program do nothing

Comment: Look at the JavaScript console in the browser for errors.

Comment: He cant find the panelSearchColor. Its a reference problem. But Why...
I have create the grid in html and with DataBind from vb

Comment: Well, you haven't shown in your question how your created it, so it's hard for me to say. You should edit the relevant bits into your question. Look at [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have edit my post so you can see how i create the grid

Comment: You seem to be just referring to controls by their ID, but in JavaScript you need to call `document.getElementById('gridFoundColors')` to get a reference to the object. Also, in Web Forms you should set the `ClientIdMode` of your controls to `static` so that the ID's on the client match the ID's on the server.

Comment: i try this. But he can't find the grid. He only find a NodeList with no entries